# Does dynamodb global replace the whole item during sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When enabling dynamodb global table, if there are two writes happens on the same item but different attributes on the table in each region. How does dynamodb sync between these two tables?

For example, in regionA, there is an update on an item:

```
{
  a: 1
}
```

at the same time, there is another write on the same table in regionB with below change:

```
{
  b: 1
}
```

will dynamodb global table sync combine the attributes into one:

```
{
 a: 1,
 b: 1
}
```

or will one replace the other?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest DDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_HowItWorks.html#V2globaltables_HowItWorks.conflict-resolution), conflict resolution happens at the *item level*, with an item meaning a collection of attributes (or database row, in traditional terms)

Unfortunately, this means that the latter the two updates will overwrite the item in its entirety. In your example, if regionB was written a millisecond later, the final state would be:

```
{
  b: 1
}
```

Under the hood, regions A and B both have a ddb stream that outputs the write that occurs, with the (NTP synced) time of update. RegionA consumes the RegionB stream, sees that the stream update is more recent than its local copy, and applies that update. RegionB consumes the RegionA stream, sees that the stream update is from *before* its local copy, and discards it. In this way, with millions of updates constantly writing to both regions, both replicas will converge toward an identical state.